# How to display first letter of name instead of image in matListAvatar?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have a mat list like below

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let person of Persons">
    <img matListAvatar src="../../../assets/images/person.svg" [alt]="person.firstName">
    <h3 matLine> {{Person.name }} </h3>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

I want to replace the avatar with first letter of first name of person if avatar is not found. How can I do that? Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ngIf` as follows. You did not mention or use it in your question but I assume each `person` object has its own avatar url saved in `person.avatar`.

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let person of Persons">

    <img *ngIf="person.avatar; else noAvatar" matListAvatar 
         [src=]"'../../../assets/images/' person.avatar + '.svg'" 
         [alt]="person.firstName">
    <ng-template #noAvatar>{{person.name.chartAt(0)}}</ng-template>

    <h3 matLine> {{Person.name }} </h3>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bunyamin Coskuner. This looks good actually.